# Using util.format, double quotes around each string in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, formatting

At the moment ..

```
var util = require("util");

var carsInput = 'seat,ford';
var cars = carsInput.split(',');

var queryString = util.format('Cars: [%s]', cars);
console.log(queryString); // Cars: [seat,ford]
```

This is the aim:

```
Cars: ["seat","ford"]
```

Is there a way to do this with `util.format` or do i need to loop and add the quotes to each element?

Comment: Did you try \"%s\"? Or does that just give ["seat,ford"] ? Sorry, I do not have an easy place to run it.

Comment: Also perhaps %c%s%c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually as simple as:

```
var util = require('util');

var carsInput = 'seat,ford';
var cars = carsInput.split(',');

var queryString = util.format('Cars: %j', cars);
console.log(queryString); // Cars: ["seat","ford"]
```

Where `%j` is for JSON

Read more on the [docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_format_format)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to not loop, at least not explicitly. It does not strictly answer your questions, since I do not have access to utils.format. Before you make your queryString say:

```
cars = cars.map(function(s){ return '"'+s+'"';});
```